# PyCharm and Type Hinting Warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, iterable, type-hinting

I have the following `property` defined on a `class`:

```
import numpy as np
import typing as tp

@property
def my_property(self) -> tp.List[tp.List[int]]:

    if not self.can_implement_my_property:
        return list()

    # calculations to produce the vector v...

    indices = list()

    for u in np.unique(v):
        indices.append(np.ravel(np.argwhere(v == u)).tolist())

    return sorted(indices, key=lambda x: (-len(x), x[0]))
```

`PyCharm` is complaining about the last line of the snippet above, signally:

> Expected type 'List[List[int]], got 'List[Iterable]' instead...

It's quite surprising, since:

- `indices` is declared as `list`
- `ravel` ensures that the matched values of `argwhere` are transformed into a one-dimensional `Numpy` vector
- `tolist` converts the one-dimensional `Numpy` vector into a list
- the obtained list is appended to the `indices` list

It might be a false positive due to a wrong handling of type hinting on IDE side, because a `List[int]` is in fact an `Iterable`... and thus `List[List[int]] = List[Iterable]`. But I can't be 100% sure about it.

Any clue about this issue? How can I ensure the returned value is enforced to the expected type?

Comment: There are a few things here ... It's unclear to me how `.tolist()` could return `List[int]` -- I'd guess it _should_ be `List[Any]` since numpy arrays currently aren't `Generic` (there also isn't any way in the type system to handle dimensionality -- you don't know if it is `List[int]` or `List[List[int]]` and so on).  You might be able to use `typing.cast` as a way to assert to the type checker that `.tolist` actually is returning a `List[int]`.  That should work with `mypy` (depending on the which stubs you're using).  I don't know about pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mgilson comment, here is the solution I implemented in order to fix the issue:

```
indices = list()

for u in np.unique(v):
    indices.append(list(it.chain.from_iterable(np.argwhere(v == u))))

return sorted(indices, key=lambda x: (-len(x), x[0]))
```